# How can I unit test an Eloquent model record being inserted in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, eloquent

Everything I've googled for relating to this suggests that you shouldn't unit test Eloquent as it's already unit tested within Laravel.

However in this case I have another class, that is not an Eloquent model, but it does insert an Eloquent model record into the database. I want to unit test this class.

For example:

```
public function methodIWantToTest()
{
    $record = new User();

    $user->name = 'Bob';
    $user->email = 'bob@example.com';

    $user->save();
}
```

How would I unit test this method? When I try it actually inserts into the database. Surely I should be able to do this without even having to go near the database?

Comment: Not a solution, but a workaround - you could `use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;` at the top of your test class. Then the record will still be inserted in the DB, but wrapped in a transaction which will be reverted after the test completes.

Answer (score 5):

if you don't want to use `seeInDatabase()` maybe you should try:

```
$mock = Mockery::mock('User');
$mock->shouldReceive('save')->once()->andReturn(true); 
$this->assertTrue(methodIWantToTest($mock));
```

Comment: It complains that I haven't called save. I think I need to dependency inject it instead, seems to work then. But not sure how that would work if I had to create multiple records. Is there nothing built into Eloquent for this? Something like Eloquent::shouldReceive('User', ['name' => 'Bob',...])?

Comment: yes you should inject it, however I don't think there is something in eloquent for that... maybe I'm wrong